# How to bind a boolean property to the rendered attribute?

Tags: jsf, facelets, el

I am using a `boolean` property in a JSF managed bean and depending on its value I have to render a command link on the facelet. But the problem is that facelets is showing this error:

> Property 'isPlayButtonEnabled' is not found on my backing bean

So I tested the code by changing the data type of the property from `boolean` to `String`.  Then facelets didn't show any error. But the command link component didn't get rendered in the view. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please post some code (property, getter&setter, partial view where the property is used).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> *Property 'isPlayButtonEnabled' is not found on my backing bean*

Remove the `is` prefix in the EL expression. It's now looking for a `isIsPlayButtonEnabled()` method. This should do:

```
<h:commandButton rendered="#{bean.playButtonEnabled}" />
```

with

```
public boolean isPlayButtonEnabled() {
    return playButtonEnabled;
}
```